# Find $P(z)$ so that $P\left(x-\frac1x\right) = x^5 - \frac1{x^5}.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $x^n - \frac1{x^n}$ is expressible as a polynomial in $x - \frac1x$ with real coefficients only if $n$ is an odd positive integer, find $P(z)$ so that $P\left(x-\frac1x\right) = x^5 - \frac1{x^5}.$

---

My brain is not working with me today!  I don't know how to start this problem.  Solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Along with the others, if you had a problem in the form $P(f(x))=g(x)$, then $P(x)=g(f^{-1}(x))$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^5 = x^5-5x^3+10x-\frac{10}{x}+\frac{5}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^5} $$
$$\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^3 = x^3-3x+\frac{3}{x}-\frac{1}{x^3}$$
hence
$$ \left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^5 + 5\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^3 +5\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)=x^5-\frac{1}{x^5}$$
and
$$ P(z) = \color{red}{z^5+5z^3+5z}.$$

Comment: Somewhere there must be a solution for $(x-\frac1{x})^{2n+1}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Don't you mean $P(z)=z^5+5z^3-5z$?

Comment: @YunaKun: no, $P(z)=z^5+5z^4\color{red}{+}5z$ is correct.

Comment: Oh wait, we're getting rid of it!  Thanks, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$(x-\frac{1}{x})^5=(x^5-\frac{1}{x^5})-5(x^3-\frac{1}{x^3})+10(x-\frac{1}{x})$$
$$(x-\frac{1}{x})^3=(x^3-\frac{1}{x^3})-3(x-\frac{1}{x})$$